# Local Elasticsearch cannot retrieve indexed documents

Tags: java, elasticsearch

For testing purposes, I want to use an embedded elastic search. Yet I am struggling to get it to work.

I tried to setup a very simple test in which I:

1. Create a local Elasticsearch
2. Create a new index
3. Index a document
4. Get the document
5. Count the number of documents in the index

It seems that everything goes fine until I count the document which constantly returns `0`.

Here is my Junit test:

```
private Node node;

@Rule
public TemporaryFolder tmp = new TemporaryFolder();

@Before
public void init() {
    Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
            .put("path.data", tmp.getRoot().getPath())
            .build();
    node = NodeBuilder.nodeBuilder().local(true)
            .settings(settings).data(true).build();
    node.start();
}

@After
public void stop() {
    node.stop();
}

@Test
public void testLocal() {
    Client client = node.client();

    // Create index
    client.admin().indices().prepareCreate("index_name").execute().actionGet();

    // Index doc
    Map<String, Object> docFields = new HashMap<>();
    docFields.put("key", "value");
    client.prepareIndex("index_name", "index_type", "1")
            .setSource(docFields).execute().actionGet();

    // Get
    GetResponse gr = client.prepareGet("index_name", "index_type", "1")
            .execute().actionGet();
    // Count
    CountResponse cr = client.prepareCount("index_name").execute().actionGet();

    Assert.assertTrue(gr.isExists());        // SUCCESS
    Assert.assertEquals(1L, cr.getCount());  // FAILURE: actual is 0
}
```

I tried several variations of this code but none was successful.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I regularly trip over this one too!

The issue that ElasticSearch is "near real-time" not actually real-time.  There is a delay (known as the refresh interval) between indexing a document and it being available to search.

The GET operation is a special case, since it uses the document's ID it can be directly loaded even before it is available to a search.

The mechanics of the situation are explained in the ElasticSearch documentation here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/near-real-time.html

For the specific issue of running local tests, you need to ensure the index is refreshed before running any queries (including count).  The [Refresh API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-refresh.html) can be used for this.  (It is considered an anti-pattern to use the Refresh API in other circumstances, however, as waiting for the refresh interval is usually the most efficient way of indexing documents.)

Comment: For the record, the missing line after indexing is: ``client.admin().indices().prepareRefresh().execute().actionGet();``